# Spurious space problem

Tags: beamer

I have a problem of spurious space, but I can't find its origin.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Dimensions et boites}{Commandes de manipulation des boites}
\parbox[c][.3\textheight][t]{\columnwidth}{%
%   \mbox{}%
    \only<+>{%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Exemple: 
        \end{itemize}
        \parbox[c][.15\textheight][c]{\columnwidth}{%
            \centering\fbox{exemple}\raisebox{0pt}{\fbox{exemple}}\fbox{exemple}%
            \vphantom{\raisebox{-1ex}{\fbox{exemple}}\raisebox{\totalheight}{\fbox{exemple}}}
        }%
    }%
    \only<+>{%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Exemple: 
        \end{itemize}
        \parbox[c][.15\textheight][c]{\columnwidth}{%
            \centering\fbox{exemple}\raisebox{1ex}{\fbox{exemple}}\fbox{exemple}
            \vphantom{\raisebox{-1ex}{\fbox{exemple}}\raisebox{\totalheight}{\fbox{exemple}}}
        }%
    }%
    \only<+>{%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Exemple: 
        \end{itemize}
        \parbox[c][.15\textheight][c]{\columnwidth}{%
            \centering\fbox{exemple}\raisebox{\totalheight}{\fbox{exemple}}\fbox{exemple}
            \vphantom{\raisebox{-1ex}{\fbox{exemple}}\raisebox{\totalheight}{\fbox{exemple}}}
        }%
    }%
    \only<+>{%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Exemple: 
        \end{itemize}
        \parbox[c][.15\textheight][c]{\columnwidth}{%
            \centering\fbox{exemple}\raisebox{-1ex}{\fbox{exemple}}\fbox{exemple}
            \vphantom{\raisebox{-1ex}{\fbox{exemple}}\raisebox{\totalheight}{\fbox{exemple}}}
        }%
    }%
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `\vphantom` construction is here to make no vertical shift between the 4 baselines.

The first slide of the frame is slightly left shifted in comparison to the next 3, as shown on the picture below, resulting a bad looking animation.

[image]

Comment: After the `\fbox{exemple}` (second, third and last slide)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `\fbox{exemple}%` in the first case but just `\fbox{exemple}` in the other cases so the spacing is out by one space.

Comment: Thanks, but why LaTex take this space into account? The paragraph is centred and this is the last space! Does `\vphantom` count as a box and not as a space?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY vphantom _is_ a box yes.

Comment: if you delete the `%` in the first case the line is longer by one space so it all moves to the left by half a space so matches the others. But really I don't think that hard Just seeing the subject line before I saw the code it was bound to be a missing `%` so I just spotted it straight away and answered although I did run the code just to check before posting.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken on the direction of the shift...